# Binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Float?' and 'Double'

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error here

```
 if car.rating <= 1.0 {

        }
```

rating is `var rating: Float?`

What i have to do to solve it?

Comment: You have to unwrap your optional, e.g. `if let rating = car.rating, rating <= 0 { ... }`. I'd suggest you read up on optionals, as it's a fairly central concept in Swift and you're going to have a hard time if you don't grok it. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330

Comment: The problem is that car.rating can be nil, so it's means car doesn't have rating. Thats the thing compiler is unhappy about. If there is no rating, is it lower than 1?

Comment: @vadian, no conversion needed here. Swift will use `1.0` as a `Float`.  Only `car.rating` needs to be unwrapped.

Comment: @Rob thank you for the suggestion i'll give a look to it

Comment: This is also a good opportunity to ask yourself if `rating` should be optional. What does it mean for your program for there to be no rating? Is that valid, or is there some default (in which case you should use a non-optional and just set it as the default). If you find yourself using `??` here, it strongly suggests that Optional was the wrong type (because there's a sensible default). If you find yourself wrapping this entire block with `if let rating = car.rating`, then that suggests Optional was the right type (because you have different behavior for nil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two variants to unwrap the optional. You can either check if the optional can be unwrapped:

```
if let rating = car.rating, rating <= 1.0
```

or

```
if car.rating != nil && car.rating! <= 1.0
```

or you can define a default value using the nil coalescing operator `??`:

```
if car.rating ?? 0 <= 1.0
```

I hope this helps to understand how optionals work in conditions.